# Openpyxl - add data validation to column (or range of columns) in for loop

Tags: python, openpyxl

How can I add my data validation to a range of columns with my for loop?

This is my data validation code:

```
dv3 = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"poor, fair, good, no mets"', allow_blank=True)
ws.add_data_validation(dv3)
```

I know I can add it to a range of cells like:

```
dv3.add("E6:K6")
```

I have a for loop that I want to add the validation to a column or range of columns in a row such as:

```
ws.cell(column=6, row=new_line_num+1, value=dv3.add("E"))
ws.cell(column=6, row=new_line_num+1, value=dv3.add("E:K"))
```

This is the full function:

def droplist(file):
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, data_only=True)
print(wb2.sheetnames)
df1 = wb2['Case List']

```
def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)
dlist = []
start_dt = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
end_dt = date.today()+ timedelta(days=21)
for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    dlist.append(dt.strftime("%m-%d"))
goodlist1 = ", ".join(dlist)
goodlist2 = "\"" + goodlist1 + "\""
print(goodlist2)

dv1 = DataValidation(type="list", formula1=goodlist2, allow_blank=True)
ws.add_data_validation(dv1)
dv1.add("E4:K4")
dv1.add('Q5')

dv2 = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"CR, PLF, MP, RM, PAE, CO, JR, TS, CG, Nella, DGC, YA, AY, BKM, JH, FS, KT, JW, EV, EO, CM, SLK, SK"', allow_blank=True)
ws.add_data_validation(dv2)
dv2.add("E5:K5")
dv2.add('O5')

dv3 = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"poor, fair, good, no mets"', allow_blank=True)
ws.add_data_validation(dv3)
dv3.add("E6:K6")
dv3.add("P5")

for row in df1.iter_rows():
    new_line_num = ws.max_row + 5
    try:
        if 'Chromosome' in row[4].value:
            print(row[0].value, row[1].value, row[4].value, row[7].value)
            ws.cell(column=1, row=new_line_num, value=row[0].value)
            ws.cell(column=2, row=new_line_num, value=row[1].value)
            ws.cell(column=5, row=new_line_num, value=row[7].value)
            ws.cell(column=3, row=new_line_num+1, value=row[6].value)
            ws.cell(column=3, row=new_line_num+2, value=row[11].value)
            ws.cell(column=4, row=new_line_num+1, value="Date:")
            ws.cell(column=4, row=new_line_num+2, value="Tech:")
            ws.cell(column=4, row=new_line_num+3, value="Quality:")
            ws.cell(column=4, row=new_line_num+4, value="Comments:")
            ws.cell(column=15, row=new_line_num+1, value="Tech:")
            ws.cell(column=16, row=new_line_num+1, value="Quality:")
            ws.cell(column=17, row=new_line_num+1, value="Date:")    
            if row[2] == "YES":
                ws.cell(column=3, row=new_line_num, value=row[12].value + ", PED") 
            else:
                ws.cell(column=3, row=new_line_num, value=row[12].value)
            
            cultures = list(row[7].value.split(' '))
            cultures2 = ' '.join(cultures).split()
            print(cultures2)
            try:
                ws.cell(column=5, row=new_line_num, value=cultures2[0])
                ws.cell(column=6, row=new_line_num, value=cultures2[1])
                ws.cell(column=7, row=new_line_num, value=cultures2[2])
                ws.cell(column=8, row=new_line_num, value=cultures2[3])
                ws.cell(column=9, row=new_line_num, value=cultures2[4])
                ws.cell(column=10, row=new_line_num, value=cultures2[5])
                ws.cell(column=11, row=new_line_num, value=cultures2[6])
                ws.cell(column=12, row=new_line_num, value=cultures2[7])
                
            except (TypeError, AttributeError, IndexError):
                continue
        else:
            continue
    except (TypeError, AttributeError):
        continue
```

I am trying to get the dv1, dv2, and dv3 into the for loop so they will populate with the data extraction from df1.

Comment: The for loop doesn't make sense. But you can apply a validation to a range of columns by specifying the max row as 1048576, which is what Excel does.

Comment: I am taking information from one Excel and putting it into another Excel document with three different data validations. My for loop iterates through the first Excel to pull information into my second Excel. Each time it pulls information from my first Excel I want to add the three different data validations below the pulled information. I don't know what the object/variable to use for the "value" in the above code.

Comment: Right, but the DataValidation has **nothing** to do with the value you put into a cell. The cells and the validation are separate tasks. If you're copying, presumably the values are from the other workbook, difficult to know because the code is incomplete.

Comment: I am not copying the validations from another workbook. I have created the data validations in the function and want them with the information I am extracting from a workbook. I can put the lists in the "value" but how do I get them to be dropdown validation lists?

Comment: To get the data validation in the for loop for a particular cell, use: dv2.add(ws.cell(column=7, row=row[0].row)). This will put the validation in the 7th column of the current row.